# Are there any good grails 2.2.1 samples to learn from?

Tags: grails, sample

I'm trying to understand more about grails and it would come in handy to have a proyect to learn from

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grails.org website was recently updated to 2.2.2, the source is at https://github.com/grails-samples/grails-website